# in IE / chrome jquery.validate.unobtrusive a little diff, how fix it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

```
              data-val="true"
              data-val-length="请填写期望小区,6-20字"
              data-val-length-min="6"
              data-val-length-max="20"
```

my input has no data-val-required.i hope it's mean that you can let it blank,or you must fill 6-20 characters. chrome make it like this. but IE make it that you must fill 6 character at least,can't let it blank.

who encounter this, and give me some tips. i think Chrome doing the right thing.

and i think maybe it's not IE's problem, but jquery.validate.unobtrusive bug. is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom validation method like this. You no longer need to use min length and maxlength attributes

```
    $.validator.addMethod("blankOrSixToTwenty", function(value, element) {
        return blankOr6_20(value);
    }, "Please leave blank or enter 6-20 Characters");


    function blankOr6_20(str,limit){
        limit = (typeof limit=='undefined')? '20' : limit;
        if(str.length == 0 || ( str.length > 5 && str.length < 21 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    validator = $("#proposal_form").validate({//enter your form id inplace of "proposal_form"
        rules: {
            proposal_url: {//"proposal_url" is the id of the input field you need to validate
                blankOrSixToTwenty: true
            }
        }

    });
```